# Set function for each array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Now I use:

```
<?php
$_POST = array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $_POST);
$_GET = array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $_GET);
$_COOKIE = array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $_COOKIE);
$_REQUEST = array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $_REQUEST);
```

but if $_POST has multiple arrays ($_POST['s'][1]) then it doesn't work. How can I set function for each array?

Comment: you really should be doing this on a case-by-case basis as you reach the database layer. Not blanketly at the top like this. For this reason, and many others. Not the least of which is this won't protect you against every attack, and it creates a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function escape_recursive($item) {
    return is_array($item) ?
        array_map("escape_recursive", $item) :
        mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}

$_POST = array_map("escape_recursive", $_POST);
// etc...

?>
```

But see DampeS8N's comment -- if you are doing this, you're doing security wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a recursive function to overcome your problem like so:

```
function recursive_array_map($input){
   if(is_array($input)){
        return array_map('recursive_array_map',$input);
   }

   return array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $input);
} 

$_POST = recursive_array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, $_POST);
```

I just wrote this inhere so not sure if it actually works ;)
Have a go at it!